# Loading time when counting numbers of followers

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Say I'll get all the followers of a certain content from my project; here is my db

```
table
  contents
  users
```

Now, everytime I want to get content's numbers of followers, I have this table here to get connections with users called **content-followers**.

```
table
  contents
  users
  content-followers <
    columns
      user_id
      content_id
```

Now my concern is say this will run getting the numbers of followers of a content, but this will be along with the other queries and stuff and I understand it may get the sql slower on process.

See, everytime people will visit the content, I'll have to show that count, but that count (as I imagine) will run through the entire table just to count.

Is there other way to make it simple? Like counting only once a certain time and save to contents table?

I have no proper database lessons so, thanks guys for your help in advance!

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, you plan on often running a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM content-followers WHERE content_id = xxx`. If that's correct, I think the most important thing is to ensure you have an index on content-followers.content_id. It would certainly be possible to use triggers to save total counts somewhere, but without more details, I worry you are overthinking this.

Comment: @EdmCoff Thanks! Yes, I might be overthinking this, and you're correct, I'm planning that kind of sql. But it's like counting rows isn't it: checking the big table of pivot and I don't like that. Anyway I have to add that I have this least answer in my head, that whenever somebody clicks on a follow button, it will add to the content-followers table and count the total, and then, save that total counts to the contents table itself; so I don't have to load and count on the pivot table over and over again. I hope to see a better solution than this. Thank you, I really appreciate your concern.

Comment: How is this a pivot table? Except for the tag, the question makes it sound like an ordinary table. Is this table actually a subquery?

Comment: But if you really want to store the counts, use triggers like I suggested. Your insert trigger can increment the appropriate count on `contents`, your delete trigger can decrement the appropriate count on `contents`, and an update trigger could see if the content-followers.content_id has changed and, if so, decrement one count and update the other. The update trigger might not be necessary if you know your application will only insert/delete records from that table and you won't do manual updates.

Comment: @EdmCoff Yes, triggers will be so helpful for easy querying! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ContentFollowers (
    user_id ...,
    content_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, content_id),
    INDEX(content_id, user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT  ...,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ContentFollowers
             WHERE user_id = u.id
        ) AS follower_count
    FROM Contents AS c
    JOIN Users AS u  ON ...
    WHERE ...
```

The `COUNT(*)` will efficiently use the `PRIMARY KEY` of `ContentFollowers`.  The added time taken will be a few milliseconds, even with many millions of users and contents.

If you want to discuss further, please provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table and your tentative `SELECT` (which will have more than what I specified).  So "... counting only once ..." should be unnecessary (and a hassle).

Is it possible for a "user" to "follow" a "content" more than once?  This is a potential hack to mess up your numbers, but I think what I say here avoids that possibility.  (A `PRIMARY KEY` includes an 'uniqueness' constraint.)  Without this, a user could repeatedly click on [Follow] to inflate the number of 'followers'.

In what you have specified *so far*, I don't see the need for a `TRIGGER`.  Furthermore, a Trigger would reopen the possibility of the above 'hack'.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of "uniqueness" that is really really helpful!